# The probability to obtain a $3$ is $p$, and the probability that there is at least one $3$ in four tosses is $0.9375$. Find $p$.

Tags: probability

I have this simple problem but, I have some problems with it:

A die is biased and the probability to obtain a $3$ is $p$. The probability that there is at least one $3$ in four tosses is $0.9375$. Find $p$.

I have tried something but without success. For example, the probability to obtain at least one 3 in 4 tosses, is the same to say the probability to not obtain zero 3 in 4 tosses.

$1-(1-p)^4 = 0.9375$

or also I have considered, with n=4:
$1-\sum_{k=1}^4 \binom{4}{k}(p)^k(1-p)^{4-k}$

can you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{lcl} 1−(1−p)^4 & = & 0.9375 \\ (1−p)^4 & = & 1-0.9375 \\ (1−p)^4 & = & .0625 \\  1−p & = & .0625^\frac{1}{4} \\ p & = & 1-.0625^\frac{1}{4} \\ p &  = & 0.5\end{array}$$

Comment: I think that this is the most rapid way.

Comment: @JB-Franco The most rapid way is to notice that $(1-p)^4=\frac{1}{16}=\frac{1}{2^4}$ and go to $1-p=\frac12$ immediatelly. That's quicker because you don't need a calculator :)

Answer (score 5):

The equation $$1-(1-p)^4=0.9375$$

is correct, you just have to solve it. First, you can rearrange it to get

$$(1-p)^4=1-0.9375$$

Now, to solve this equation, first let me just give you some hints:

- Try to first calculate what $(1-p)$ is equal to, it's easier.
- $0.9375 = \frac{15}{16}$
- $16=2^4$

Comment: sorry, the only thing I don't understand is why $0.9375 = \frac{15}{16}$

Comment: @JB-Franco Do you understand why $0.5=\frac12$?

Comment: now, one thing I can say that on the calculator $1 \div 2 = 0.5$. But certainly there is something other to say.

Comment: @JB-Franco Are you telling me you don't know what "decimal notation" is? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal

Comment: yes, but, I would have never taken this way of proceeding. You say that $\frac{9375}{10000}$ and divide by $5^4 = 625$ I obtain $\frac{15}{16}$.

Comment: @JB-Franco Exactly. Or, you can just type $\sqrt[4]{1-0.9375}$ into the calculator and notice that it is equal to $0.5$.

Answer (score 2):

The first equation $1 - (1-p)^4 = 0.9375$ is correct.

It's simple when you realize that $0.9375 = \frac{15}{16}$. I can't say how I saw this, but when you take the difference of this from $1$, you get $0.0625$, which strikes familiarity with being a power of $5$, so probably any intuition must have come from there. Then, we have: $$ 1 -
 \frac{15}{16} = (1-p)^4 \implies (1-p)^4 = \frac{1}{16}$$

This shows that $(1-p) = \frac12$ is the only meaningful possibility from the above, and hence $p = \frac 12$.